# Android: Getting Configured Corporate Email ID Programmatically

Tags: android, exchange-server, email-client

I am using the default email client of Android (**Native Email App**) to configure my Corporate account. I am using Exchange server Account. I am using myname.pfx file as a mode of authentication. After setting up my mail, i could sync with my account.

I need to get the email id that i configured in my device. I could do it using **AccountManger, Account class and a string which holds my account name**. But the problem is, the email client accepts other mail id (say **abc@cba.com**) also and get configured with my certificate

At this point `AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts()` is giving **"abc@cba.com"** as one of its returned value. But i need the account name as my original mail id for which the email app is synced..

Plz help me on this.

Thanks in Advance